# Bundle options could not be deleted from admin - js issue

Tags: magento2, javascript, magento2.2, magento2.2.2

I have bundle options more than one page. While deleting one of the options on the first page, the bundle options from the second page are getting deleted. This seems to be a Js issue in *Magento_Bundle/js/components/bundle-dynamic-rows.js*

Version Used - Magento 2.2.2

Could anyone help in sorting this issue!

[image]

Comment: Did you try with deployment command?

Comment: Yes, And It has been checked with a fresh installation of Magento 2.2.2.

Comment: @Haritha any solutions for this?